# Cache on demand feature for cached map services

Tags: arcgis-server

I have a cached map service that I am using in a Silverlight based application. For this cached service, I have cached a core area and checked the option for On Demand Cache. I find that the areas within On Demand Cache are very slow. I am trying to understand how this process works. If I am zoomed in at the scale of 4000, it should be generating cache for a very small area, not sure why it takes much longer. I am using ArcGIS online tiling scheme. Does it generate the cache for all scale levels or just the one level.

I am looking for some feedback.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Hmmm... It's about time you accepted some of the great answers you've gotten to your previous questions, like [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13291/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-utm-zone-from-a-lat-long-point/13292#13292). All you have to do is tick the checkmark icon next to the best answer: that makes it more prominent to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only generates the cache for one scale level, but as described [here](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2010/09/13/ArcGIS-Server-10.0-improvements-to-map-cache-tile-generation.aspx), the caching engine only works on a minimum "supertile" of 2048 x 2048 pixels, which if you're using the Google/Bing Maps tiling scheme is 16 x 16 tiles. If you're at the intersection of several supertiles, the server could potentially be generating 1000 tiles from one request, even though you're only seeing 10-20 of them in your application.

Comment: What I do most often to combat the slowness issue is to pre-generate areas most frequently visited by users.  This may not always be possible however, but it is extremely effective when it is possible.  If for example you're displaying a state, and you are fairly sure your users will most often be viewing the metropolitan areas, you can pre-generate the tiles for those areas at the required scales.

Answer (score 1):

Bringing back an old question for a quick update; cache on demand performs **very** poorly.

This is still an issue in ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 and the problem extends back to at least version 10.1. There is a bug report about this issue here: http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4Njg1Mw==