# Fail to publish GP as a service

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I have no idea what the issue is here, I created this scripting tool which works fine when I run it through ArcGIS desktop. **However, for some reason, I am unable to publish the tool as a service**.The following is the error (00178) that I keep receiving:

"Data: \, used by script cannot be copied to the server". The script is very simple as it is just doing a simple calculation derived from a feature class which is currently stored on the SDE geodatabase. I've already looked through the documentation and none of the solution seems to resolve my issue.

```
    import arcpy, csv, datetime

    output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    DATA = r'C:\!PROD_Connections_SDE\PROD@ABC.sde\ABC.PROD.S2_testbuild\ABC.PROD.ABC_testline'

    #table = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(DATA,"data")

    # Map of UTM Zone WKIDs, modify as needed
    utmZones = {10: 32610,
        11: 32611,
        12: 32612,
        13: 32613}

        pLength = 0.0
        hLength = 0.0

       def getUTMZone(geometry):
       #http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13291/computing-utm-zone-from-lat-long-point
           from math import floor
           geo = geometry.projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
           lon = geo.trueCentroid.X
           return int(floor((lon + 180)/6) + 1)

       with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(DATA,["SHAPE@","Activity"]) as cur:
           for row in cur:
               utmZone = getUTMZone(row[0])
               sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(utmZones[utmZone])

               # Project line to correct UTM zone and add its length to the correct sum
               geom = row[0].projectAs(sr)
               if row[1] == "HDD":
                   hLength += geom.length
               else:
                   pLength += geom.length

       # Write data to CSV
       with open(output,'wb') as outFile:
           date = datetime.datetime.today()
           headers = ("Date","P Total Length (m)","H Total Length (m)")
           record = (str(date),str(plength),str(hlength))
           writer = csv.writer(outFile)
           writer.writerow(headers)
           writer.writerow(record)
```

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain the full error message as text.  Have you tried resolving the error as per the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//015400000601000000)?

Comment: of course i have

Comment: Then please **edit** the question to include the details of the procedure you used to register your data source with the server.

Comment: Your indentation on `def getUTMZone(geometry):` seems to be astray, but in any event I think you should try publishing just a snippet of code as a Geoprocessing Service first, before returning to your full code.

Comment: What version of AGS? Based on this: **Data: \,**, my best guess is the SDE data. There is no where else in your script with a " \ ". However its strange it is just the slash and not the full path to the dataset.

Comment: that's exactly what I was puzzled with. I'm currently using AGS 10.2.2

Answer (score 2):

The analyser likes to pick out random items and claim the script is using them, for example [this post on Geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/160355).

I got round the problem by putting the SDE connection file on a network share that the server could also see and referencing it with a full UNC path:

```
INWorkspace = r"\\store\UTILITIES\SDE Connections\xxx_geodb.sde"
```