# Reference meridian of longitude in UTM conversion

Tags: utm

I'm not a GIS professional.

I'm trying to write a code to convert from lat/long to UTM coordinates using this truncated method given in Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Simplified_formulae

What values I should use for lambda_0 (reference meridian of longitude)?

Comment: UTM is divided into zones, with each zone (presumably) having a different reference meridian of longitude. You'll need to determine the UTM zone projection of your coordinates to find the lambda_0, I believe.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Question and answer on find the zone based on a lat,lon point: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13291/computing-utm-zone-from-lat-long-point

Comment: please, use one of the many well known and supported libraries that already exist to do this. See http://proj4.org/ for example

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the reference meridian and the UTM zone from the longitude of your point like this :

Zone = Floor((long + 186°) / 6))

lambda_0 = Zone * 6° - 183°

Make sure to keep the Zone and Hemisphere information along with each pair of E-N coordinates, especially if your points span several zones.